# Create a Docker container without internet access

Tags: networking, firewall, docker

What's the simplest way to create an isolated Docker container that doesn't have any internet access whatsoever?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [**none** network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks): "The none network adds a container to a container-specific network stack. That container lacks a network interface"

For example, you can run a container without network interfaces attached to it specifying none as the network:

```
docker run --net none -it alpine  /bin/sh
```

See that only the loopback interface is attached:

```
/ # ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```